# Computing all orbits induced by group $G$ acts on a linear space $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

**Problem**: $V$ is linear space with dimension $n$, $G$ is a group of  all invertible transformation on $V$ that its representation matrix is an upper triangular matrix. Considering $G$ acts on $V$ by $gx:=g(x)$, compute all its orbits.

I know an orbit: $\{0\}$ and if the $k$th coordinate component $x_k\neq 0$ while $x_l=0$ for all $l＞k$, I think $\mathrm{Orb}(x)$ is the family of all elements satisfied the $k$th $\neq 0$ while $l$th$=0$ for every $l＞k$. However, I can't achieve this idea.

Comment: Are you saying that $G$ consists of all linear maps with upper triangular matrix? At the moment, you have just defined $G$ to be some arbitrary group consisting of matrices of that form - so $G$ could be the trivial group, for example.

Comment: Sorry!$G$ consists of all univertible linear translation with upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Then your conjecture about ${\rm Orb}(x)$ is correct. It's no hard to prove.

Comment: I recognize it is a linear algebra problem and I observe that I only prove:for every $x$ and $y$ satisfied the $n$th coordinate component $x_n\neq 0$,there exist a upper univertible matrix $A$ such that $Ax=y$. But I can't find this matrix...

Comment: You don't have to do it for all $x$ and $y$, you can take $x$ to be the vector with $x_k \ne 0$ and $x_j=0$ for $j = k$, and then it's easy.

Comment: Why? I think I need some concrete hint.If $x$ and $y$ are those vectors,how we  find a univertible upper triangular matrix $A$

Comment: I know how to find univertible matrix A : I can extend $x$ and $y$ to become two basis containing $x$ and $y$, then there exist a univertible  matrix $A$ which maps one basis to another.But this skill seems useless in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ consists of all $n \times n$ invertible upper triangular matrices, and $G$ acts (from the left) on vector space $V$.

The claim is that the orbits of $G$ on $V$ are the sets $O_k$ with $0 \le k \le n$, where $O_0 = \{0\}$, and for $k > 0$, $O_k$ consists of those vectors $v$ with $v_k \ne 0$ and $v_j = 0$ for all $j>k$.

Since the matrices in $G$ are invertible, they have nonzero elements on the diagonal, and so, for each $k$, $G$ maps vectors in $O_k$ to vectors in $O_k$.

It remains to prove that each $O_k$ is a complete orbit. For this, fix $k$, let $x$ be the vector with $x_k=1$ and $x_j = 0$ for $j \ne k$, and let $y$ be an arbitrary vector in $O_k$.

It is sufficient to prove that there is some element of $G$ that maps $x$ to $y$. But we can just choose any matrix having $y$ as its $k$-th column - the other entries do not matter - and that will map $x$ to $y$.

Comment: I get your idea.

Comment: I can choose a matrix: $$ \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & I_{n-k} \\  \end{pmatrix} $$. $A_1$ is a $k×k$ univertible upper triangular  matrix with proper $k$-th column (In this column, every element should take factor $x_k^{-1}$